# How to get error event details in Firefox using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to understand why Firefox (I'm using 15 but it's the same even in nightly) is not behaving like WebKit when trying to access error event information.

This one works everywhere:

```
window.onerror = function(message, lineno, filename) { }
```

But of course I don't want to use this.

The right thing to do is:

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(e) { 
  console.log(e.message);
}, false);
```

Unfortunately this one only works in WebKit. In Firefox the handler is called, but the `e` event is almost empty: no message, no line number, no filename properties.

The very minimal test is here: http://jsbin.com/efexiw/1/edit

I don't think this is a bug, though... so the question is: how do I get the error details in recent Firefox?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [HTML5 specification requires](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#creating-scripts) that a parse failure causes the browser to:

> ...report the error for script, with the problematic position (line number and column number), using the global object... as the target.

Where "[report the error](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#report-the-error)" includes the steps

> 4. Let *message* be a user-agent-defined string describing the error in a helpful manner.
>
> ...
>
> 7. Let *event* be a new trusted `ErrorEvent` object that does not bubble but is cancelable, and which has the event name `error`.
> 8. Initialize *event*'s `message` attribute to *message*.
>
> ...
>
> 13. Dispatch *event* at *target*.

Thus, any HTML5-compliant browser will report parse-time error events on `window`, which include a `message` attribute set to a "*user-agent-defined string describing the error in a helpful manner.*" Any browser version that fails to do this is not yet HTML5 compliant in this regard.

---

Previously (at the time this question was written), `window.onerror` gave information that was not provided by `window.addEventListener("error")`. If you must use an old version of Firefox, you can [safely use `window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror#Example):

> ```
> // Example 1:
>
> // Prevent error dialogs from displaying -which is the window's normal
> // behavior- by overriding the default event handler for error events that
> // go to the window.
> window.onerror = null;
>
> // Example 2:
>
> var gOldOnError = window.onerror;
> // Override previous handler.
> window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
>   if (gOldOnError)
>     // Call previous handler.
>     return gOldOnError(errorMsg, url, lineNumber);
>
>   // Just let default handler run.
>   return false;
> }
> ```

Comment: I accept the answer because at least I know how to handle the situation. Too bad I did not understand why Firefox _seems_ to have removed this "feature" (for what I've been reading in my searches are old examples which there are supposed to work in FF and other browsers).

Comment: In FF 38, at least, probably much sooner, the error event provided to addEventListener has at least message, filename and lineno properties... maybe more. I'm presently on a search for more, and for any standard that defines particulars.

Comment: Details of error event are lacking, but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent) shows .colno available, and experimentation says .error.stack is available in FF38.