# In Angular.js $exceptionHandler how can we find out the name of the controller in which the exception occurred?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

```
angular.module('exceptionOverride', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', function (){
  return function (exception, cause) {
    throw exception;
  };
});
```

This is the example on `angularjs` website, however the exception does not have details of the exception's source

so if inside a controller named `demoController` I throw an exception - `throw "fakex"`

how can i find out that the exception happened in `demoController`?

Comment: have a look at [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2542-logging-client-side-errors-with-angularjs-and-stacktrace-js.htm)

Comment: had a look at that link, it uses stacktrace.js which is of course not a part of angular. Using a third party library is the last option. How can native angular report the controller name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get error event details in Firefox using addEventListener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746034/how-to-get-error-event-details-in-firefox-using-addeventlistener)