# How get global errors from DOM (<img>, <script> and <iframe>)?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Note:** that the question is different from [How to get error event details in Firefox using addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12746034/1518921)

I need to get the **details/message** from all HTTP errors in a page, if set `useCapture=true`, I get all errors, including HTTP errors (these are the errors I need), I got using `useCapture` param:

```
addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);
```

Example:

- Javascript:

  ```
    window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }, true);
  ```
- html:

  ```
    <script src="http://invalidurl010101010/file.js"></script>
  ```

But I can not catch the error **details**.

If I use this:

- Javascript:

  ```
    window.onerror = function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    };
  ```
- html:

  ```
    <script src="http://invalidurl010101010/file.js"></script>
  ```

But that does not catch the HTTP error, I would like to pick up any HTTP error occurs, from `<img>`, `<script>` and `<iframe>`.
How get error details from HTTP errors in DOM elements with Javascript?

How get **HTTP errors** details from DOM elements with Javascript? Is it possible?